# I a have a SQL 1066 - Not unique table/alias:

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables
1 project
2 project id, campaign id
3 campaign
I need to make a search in all on those tables join I trying to make en inner join I keep getting

> 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'pp086_projects'

I am searching for "Next Nine" it is in campaign.

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `PP086_projects`, `PP086_project_users`,pp086_project_companies
JOIN `PP086_projects` ON `PP086_projects`.id = pp086_project_companies.project_id
JOIN pp086_project_companies ON  pp086_companies.id==pp086_project_companies.company_id
WHERE (`PP086_projects`.`id` = `PP086_project_users`.`project_id`
       AND `PP086_project_users`.`user_id` = '2')
  AND ( name LIKE '%Next Nine%'
       OR name LIKE 'Next Nine'
       OR description LIKE 'Next Nine'
       OR pp086_project_companies.name LIKE 'Next Nine' )
```

Comment: Note:  I removed the sql-server tag because the syntax suggests MySQL.

Comment: You are mixing old and new style JOIN.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing implicit and explicit `join` syntax.  As a result, you have put the table `PP086_projects` into the `from` clause twice.  This is probably the cause of your problem.

As a simple rule, just don't use `,` in the `from` clause.  If you want a cross join, use `cross join` explicitly:

```
SELECT *
FROM `PP086_projects` join
      `PP086_project_users`
      on `PP086_projects`.`id` = `PP086_project_users`.`project_id`
      pp086_project_companies
      ON `PP086_projects`.id = pp086_project_companies.project_id JOIN
      pp086_project_companies
      ON  pp086_companies.id = pp086_project_companies.company_id
WHERE (`PP086_project_users`.`user_id` = '2') AND
      ( name LIKE '%Next Nine%'
              OR name LIKE 'Next Nine'
              OR description LIKE 'Next Nine'
              OR pp086_project_companies.name LIKE 'Next Nine'
      );
```

Comment: Probably you should change the latest pp086_project_companies join to pp086_companies. At least pp086_project_companies is joined 2 times, but pp086_companies not, and this latest one is also used.

Comment: i have the same error 1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'pp086_project_companies'

Answer (score 0):

You use the `PP086_projects` table more times. You should alias the different instances of it.
This is ambiguous for example: `PP086_projects.id`

Or if this is unintentional, probably you should remove the table's name after the FROM like this:

```
      SELECT * FROM `PP086_projects`
      JOIN `PP086_project_users` ON `PP086_projects`.`id` = `PP086_project_users`.`project_id`
      JOIN `pp086_project_companies` ON `PP086_projects`.id = pp086_project_companies.project_id
      JOIN pp086_companies ON  pp086_companies.id== pp086_project_companies.company_id
       WHERE ( AND `PP086_project_users`.`user_id` = '2') AND ( name LIKE '%Next Nine%'
      OR name LIKE 'Next Nine'
      OR description LIKE 'Next Nine'
      OR pp086_project_companies.name LIKE 'Next Nine' )
```